# Manipulate string data

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python and trying to create a script to modify the output of a JS file to match what is required to send data to an API. The JS file is being read via urllib2.

```
def getPage():
    url = "http://url:port/min_day.js"
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return response.read()

# JS Data
# m[mi++]="19.12.12 09:30:00|1964;2121;3440;293;60"
# m[mi++]="19.12.12 09:25:00|1911;2060;3277;293;59"

# Required format for API
# addbatchstatus.jsp?data=20121219,09:25,3277.0,1911,-1,-1,59.0,293.0;20121219,09:30,3440.0,1964,-1,-1,60.0,293.0
```

As a breakdown (Required values are bold)

m[mi++]="**19.12.12** **09:30:00**|**1964**;2121;**3440**;**293**;**60**"

and need to add values of -1,-1 into the string

I've managed to get the date into the correct format and replace characters and line breaks to make the output look as such, but I have a feeling I'm heading down the wrong track if I need to be able to reorder this string values. Although it looks like the order is in reverse in regards to time as well.

```
20121219,09:30:00,1964,2121,3440,293,60;20121219,09:25:00,1911,2060,3277,293,59
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm thinking along the lines of regex might be what I need.

Comment: You said you have to add -1,-1 to the string - where in the string does that need to be added?

Comment: If you take a look at the # addbatchstatus.jsp line you can see where values need to be added. 1911,-1,-1,59.0

Comment: Why is `2121` (not required according to you) in your output?

Comment: This is a DC power voltage that isn't supported by the API. And I have no idea how to strip this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Regex pattern to strip out the bits you don't want

> `m\[mi\+\+\]="(?P<day>\d{2})\.(?P<month>\d{2})\.(?P<year>\d{2}) (?P<time>[\d:]{8})\|(?P<v1>\d+);(?P<v2>\d+);(?P<v3>\d+);(?P<v4>\d+);(?P<v5>\d+).+`

and replace with

> `20\P<year>\P<month>\P<day>,\P<time>,\P<v3>,\P<v1>,-1,-1,\P<v5>,\P<v4>`

This pattern assumes that the characters before the date are constant. You can replace `m\[mi\+\+\]="` with `[^\d]+` if you want more general handling of that bit.

So to put this in practice in python:

```
import re

def getPage():
    url = "http://url:port/min_day.js"
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return response.read()    

def repl(match):
    return '20%s%s%s,%s,%s,%s,-1,-1,%s,%s'%(match.group('year'),
                                            match.group('month'),
                                            match.group('day'),
                                            match.group('time'),
                                            match.group('v3'),
                                            match.group('v1'),
                                            match.group('v5'),
                                            match.group('v4'))

pattern = re.compile(r'm\[mi\+\+\]="(?P<day>\d{2})\.(?P<month>\d{2})\.(?P<year>\d{2}) (?P<time>[\d:]{8})\|(?P<v1>\d+);(?P<v2>\d+);(?P<v3>\d+);(?P<v4>\d+);(?P<v5>\d+).+')

data = [re.sub(pattern, repl, line).split(',') for line in getPage().split('\n')]

# If you want to sort your data
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True)

# If you want to write your data back to a formatted string
new_string = ';'.join(','.join(x) for x in data)

# If you want to write it back to file
with open('new/file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_string)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome, that's a great starting point for me. Thank you very much for going to the trouble. Running the code if I simply print the output all I'm seeing is the following: [['20\\P<year>\\P<month>\\P<day>', '\\P<time>', '\\P<v3>', '\\P<v1>', '-1', '-1', '\\P<v5>', '\\P<v4>'], ['20\\P<year>\\P<month>\\P<day>', '\\P<time>', '\\P<v3>', '\\P<v1>', '-1', '-1', '\\P<v5>', '\\P<v4>']

Comment: Sorry about that, I seem to be out of practice with my python regexing :/
I've edited the code, see if that helps :)

Comment: You're still doing much better than I! Now I'm receiving line 31, in repl match.group('v4')) TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str. I've tried changing the value to a %s without any luck. If you do want to do any of your own testing I've uploaded the file url = "http://www.nealedgeworth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/min_day.js"

Comment: Legend! I did try similar but didn't replace the floats :)